# How to pass parameters to an Ember Route

Tags: ember.js

Please see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xakok/1/edit

How do I do the following?  The categories display.  When user clicks on a category, I want to  bring up a list of links that belong to the category that was clicked. Ember seems to be by-passing my LinkRoute all together.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you provide a model to the link-to helper it will skip the model hook (it built the url based on the model, and assumes that's the model that would be used for that route).

That being said you need to handle the case where you refresh the page instead of hitting the page using the link-to.

Solving the first, we can now assume the category model is being sent to the links route as its model.  So we can update the template to iterate over the links on the category sent in. (you could also say each link in model.links, where the category is your model).

```
{{#each link in links}}
  {{link.title}}<br/>
{{/each}}
```

But you need to be able to handle the case where we refresh the page as well.  So we change the link route to mimic the behavior and return the same type of model the link-to is passing in.

```
App.LinkRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('category', params.category_id);
    }
});
```

Lastly, using the fixture adapter, when you define a `hasMany` or `belongsTo` as `3` or `[1,2,3]` you need to specify those relationships as async.

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  links: DS.hasMany('link', {async:true})
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fexelera/1/edit

Lastly, thanks for providing source and all that was necessary for your problem, the jsbin really helps people answer questions easily.

Comment: Thank you @kinkpin2K for your answer and explanation.  You are a gentleman and a scholar!